# Which books are used today to learn discrete-event simulation?

Tags: python, simpy, event-simulation

I just got enrolled in a program that starts me in researches about new *Networks Protocols*, and my first assignment is to learn about **Discrete-Event Simulation**.

It was recommended 2 books:

[Simulating Computer Systems: Techniques and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026213229X) by  **Myron H. MacDougall**

[Simulation Model Design and Execution: Building Digital Worlds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130986097) by **Paul Fishwick**

Both books use tools that I won't be using in particularly but I was told it is a good book to learn the basics of simulation of discrete-events.

But, as it happens, the MacDougall's book isn't really available in any other store except amazon dot com, and would take 2 months to deliver it to my address. And the Fishwick's book would cost a fortune that i'm not willing to spend right now.

Now, I come here to ask **which books are used today to learn discrete-event simulation that are similar to those?**

P.S.: I will be using the SimPy simulation tool based on Python.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a temporary workaround may be to find those eBook/digital versions of some of those books online (pdfs) or search [Google Books](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=discrete-event+simulation&tbm=bks)

Comment: In fact, I was hoping to someone say a free eBook that I could download easily. Thanks!

Comment: I would have, but since this is a public site, I don't want to get flagged or banned :) Just google search those titles with `pdf`, etc

Comment: Well, thanks anyway @downshift :^)

Comment: have you tried you public library, I was surprised at their e-book and digital resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many excellent resources for learning about discrete-event simulation. Probably the top selling book of the last 35 years has been "Simulation Modeling and Analysis" by Law.  Other fine choices include "Discrete-Event System Simulation" by Banks, Carson, & Nelson, "Principles of Discrete-Event Simulation" by Fishman, "Discrete-Event Simulation: A First Course" by Leemis & Park, or "Graphical Simulation Modeling and Analysis Using SIGMA for Windows" by Schruben, to name a few.

Another alternative would be to go to the [Winter Simulation Conference Archive](http://informs-sim.org), pick any year, and check out the articles in either the introductory or advanced tutorials.  I'd particularly recommend Schriber's [Inside Discrete-Event Simulation Software: How It Works and Why It Matters](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc15papers/001.pdf) series, and [Fundamentals of Simulation Modeling](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc07papers/007.pdf) by Sanchez.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who still stumble upon this question while looking for resources, apart from all the books mentioned in pjs's answer (out of which I found "Discrete-Event System Simulation" by Banks, Carson, Nelson & Nicol and "Simulation Modeling and Analysis" by Law & Kelton to be most helpful) **'Simulation' by Ross** is another very useful resource.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend my own book, which is focussed on designing and implementing simulation models, unlike most classical "Discrete-Event System Simulation" textbooks, which are focussed on statistics and operations research.

*[Discrete Event Simulation Engineering](https://sim4edu.com/reading/des-engineering/) - How to design discrete event simulations with DPMN and implement them with OESjs, Simio and AnyLogic*

It's still a draft version, the HTML version is Open Access (free).